# Sumar un día a una fecha en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

En mi vista tengo esto:

```
            @include('Componentes.simpleInput',['name'=>'fecha_fin','label'=>'Fecha fin','type'=>'date','value'=>date_format(date_create($condicionComercial->fecha_fin),'Y-m-d')])
```

¿cómo puedo hacer para sumarle un día a esa fecha?
recuerdo que era algo de .+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para manejo de fechas en **laravel**, [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) es lo mejor, Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
@include('Componentes.simpleInput',['name'=>'fecha_fin','label'=>'Fecha fin','type'=>'date','value'=>\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$condicionComercial->fecha_fin )->addDay()->toDateTimeString()]);
```

Con [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) puedes hacer operaciones con las fechas como sumar, restar, comparaciones y muchas otras cosas como la Localización, ademas de que ya viene con **laravel** solo lo utilizas y ya.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar un objeto DateTime y agregarle un día con DateInterval de la siguente manera:

```
@include('Componentes.simpleInput',['name'=>'fecha_fin','label'=>'Fecha fin','type'=>'date','value'=>(new DateTime($fecha_fin))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d')])
```